# Declaration of Child method should be compatible with Parent method

Tags: php, class, oop

> Warning:  Declaration of Child::default_action($form_id) should be compatible with Parent::default_action()

I know I lack in the department of understanding object coding and I luck up fixing things some times but in this message I am try to understand why something worked.

I was getting the error message above in the php error log. The original parent method is

```
 function default_action() {
       echo "<html><body></body></html>";
 }
```

I changed it to

```
  function set_default_action() {
       echo "<html><body></body></html>";
  }
```

The error messages in the log went away. Now I am trying to find out why did this work. I put it there because I saw in the code `set_current_action`. I kind of have an idea that `set_` `get_` some others are commands that precede the method declaration or something like that.

Comment: Well it would help if you showed us the complete 2 classes

Comment: If the parent METHOD has a parameter then the subclassed method must also have the same parameter(s) If it does not then the subclasses method cannot have a parameter

Comment: https://github.com/openemr/openemr/blob/master/library/classes/Controller.class.php is a link to the full class

Comment: That is what I thought in what I found. The effect was when I added the parameter that was in the child to the parent all the other classes started failing.

Comment: So your child (subclassed) methid cannot have the `$form_id` parameter

Comment: but I tried to pass by reference by that caused a new issue

Comment: ___Why did this work___ Because `set_default_action` is not overriding the `default_action` because the name is different

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/120725/discussion-between-user1794918-and-riggsfolly).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the function declaration for the parent and child are not compatible (like the error says)

`public function method([$args])` is the function declaration.

In your case the parent method does not take any parameters but the child method does, so you get the error.

To solve this you should have the parent method accept the same parameters as the child method. You will probably want to provide some sensible default for the parameters.

```
//parent class
function default_action($form_id = null) {
```

As RiggsFolly points out, you may not have control over the parent class and have to make your child class conform. In that case you can use a class property to pass the form id to the method.

```
//Child class

class Child extends Parent{
    public $form_id;

    function setFormId($form_id){
      $this->form_id = $form_id;

    }
    function default_action(){
        //Work with $this->form_id
    }

}

//In code
$form_id = 123;
$C = new Child();
$C->setFormId($form_id);
$C->default_action();
```

Comment: Unless you dont have control over the parent class and then you just have to conform to the parent restriction